# Excluding symbolic links from dir

Tags: ubuntu

I want to exclude symbolic links from a directory listing. I have been using the following command:

```
dir --ignore=@ -F
```

But the symbolic links are still being listed as showed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWxi4.png

How can I exclude them when using the dir command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`--ignore` does not work on types, it works on patterns. For example, if you have files:

```
$ ls 
a.txt b.dat c.txt d.dat
$ ls --ignore='*.txt'
b.dat d.dat
```

There is no easy way to filter out symlinks, but you can try using `grep`

```
ls -F | grep -v "@"
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps me understand.

Comment: That would also filter out files whose name contains `@`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` to exclude the symbolic links:

```bash
find -maxdepth 1 ! -type l ! -path './.*' -ls
```

With `! -type l` I'm excluding the symbolic links. Therefore directories, regular files, special files, etc. will be displayed.
And with `! -path './.*'` I'm excluding hidden files (e.g. `.bashrc`,`.profile`)

If you want to have output as `ls` or `dir` the  you should use:

```
#With color
find -maxdepth 1 ! -type l ! -path './.*' -exec ls --color=yes -Fd {} +

#No color
find -maxdepth 1 ! -type l ! -path './.*' -exec ls -Fd {} +
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: Beware that on the OP's Ubuntu that fails to exclude the hidden files whose name cannot be decoded as text in the user's locale.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you for the suggestion. Could you provide some example or link about that? I did not understand how this could fail but it should be very useful if you provide some example/link. *"files whose name cannot be decoded as text"*  I think this applies for special characters but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

With the `zsh` shell, you can use its [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to filter files by their type in glob expansions.

```
dir -Fd -- *(^@)
```

Would call `dir` with the non-hidden files in the current directory that are *not* (`^`) of type *symlink* (`@`) as arguments.

If you just need to see the list, you don't even need to call `dir` (or its more Unixy `ls` equivalent), you can pass them to `zsh`'s `print` builtin.

For instance:

```
print -rC1 -- *(^@)
```

Would `print` them `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn.

Using the `M`ark qualifier adds a `/` at the end of files of type *directory* like `dir -F` does though that's only for directories

```
print -rC1 -- *(M^@)
```